# Can I still use my return ticket after failing to board my first outbound ticket?

Tags: air-travel, bookings, airlines, alitalia

I purchased Alitalia Round trip tickets. Unfortunately, I wont be able to make the first flight out due to a conflict in schedule. But I will be able to make the return flight of the said roundtrip ticket. Would this cause me any problem during my return flight such as forfeiture of my return ticket? What should I do? It’s been really hard to get consistent answers from their hotline and they’re not really good in terms of customer service. Please help its my first time booking and it costs a lot to call their hotline from my country aside from the fact that I get inconsistent answers from their agents :(

Comment: Is this question about future? I.e. do you already missed the outbound flight, or also this is in future?  In first case is a "no show", in the second case, you may contact the airline. About contacting airline: you may check email or "web form" contact. Sometime they have twitter and facebook support

Comment: Yes, because we made a mistake in booking hence we wont be able to make the outbound flight. But still intend to use the return flight? I already asked help immediately through their hotline within 24hrs of booking. However the agents I talked to were in consistent (i called three times so i talked to three different agents and they gave me three different answers) i waited for a reply  via email (because i also emailed them) yet they still didnt answer

Comment: Usually, a no-show on the outbound segment means the airline will automatically cancel the return. Alitalia’s T&C state: 
3.3.8. The Ticket purchased by the passenger is valid only for the segment or segments specified on the Ticket,  from the place of departure to the place of destination, including any stopover. [..] If the purchased Ticket includes a series of segments, these have to be used in the prescribed order. Can you reschedule the outbound flight? Or cancel entirely? You might be able to do this online?

Comment: - my question so we decided to avoid the first flight but still use the return flight. Is there any way around this? :(

Comment: If it is about future, you may check ticket condition: you may be able to change dates (for a fee). Or if you have a good reason, sometime they keep the ticket (but they should be notified in time).

Comment: @traveller unfortunately I cant reschedule. And we’ve been relying on this return ticket.. is there like some kind of a holding fee instead of totally cancelling the return ticket...

Comment: @giacomo may i have an idea of what’s a good reason. I know that a mistake in booking is not really a good reason since strictly speaking - should not happen when booking :( - i am just worried they won’t accept human error as a good enough excuse lol

Answer (score 5):

Depends a bit on the airline policy and the specific fare class and ticket rules.

In most cases, the airlines will simply cancel your return ticket as soon as you miss any leg of your itinerary. If you want to salvage your return flight you need to execute a change: you need to change the return ticket to a one-way ticket. You will have to pay a change fee (depending on your fare class and ticket conditions) and the difference in price between your original ticket and the new one-way ticket. In the unlikely event that the new ticket is cheaper, you can credit the difference against the change fee.

In most cases with this will be quite expensive and it's good practice to shop for alternative tickets so you know what your options are before you call.

Some "basic" or "light" tickets cannot be changed and you'll loose the entire ticket if you don't fly it exactly as booked.

Comment: Note: "Non-reimbursable" tickets have reimbursable taxes (which are often high, so better then nothing).